# PHPのエラーログを日本時間にしたい

Tags: php

PHPのエラーログを日本時間、若しくはdate.timezoneに合わせたいですがどうしたらよいでしょうか？

```
shell> tail /var/log/php_errors.php
[22-Apr-2015 16:42:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function setup_post_data() in /path/to/hoge on line XX
```

php.iniの抜粋は下記のようになっています.

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo'
...(省略)....
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
```

過去に強制UTCから修正された、とアナウンスがあった気がしてたのですがJSTなログはもうずっと見ていません。
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60723

PHPはMac OSXのhomebrewから入れた物です。

```
shell> php -v
PHP 5.6.7 (cli) (built: Mar 23 2015 01:51:22)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: PHPのバージョンを記載してもらえないでしょうか（`php -v` もしくは `phpinfo()` などで確認できます）

Comment: 申し訳無いです、入れるつもりでスッカリ忘れてました。

Comment: HOTTAさんと同じバージョンですね・・・となると、見ているphp.iniが間違っているか、実行時に変更されてしまっている気がします。HOTTAさんと同じように、シェル上で `php -r "printx();"` を実行し、そのログを確認してみてください。

Comment: 修正されました！！
`[11-May-2015 14:56:40 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Stack trace:`となりました。
最近はJSTではなくてAsia/Tokyoと表示されるんですね。ううーん、前からcliでも試していたのですが何が契機だったか不明です。
HOTTAさんと同じくsyslogで受けてやればこの問題は起きなさそうですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いつも syslog に出していたので、自前で出せることを忘れてました。
早速使ってみましたが、正しく出ているようです。

```
$ php -v | head -1
PHP 5.6.7 (cli) (built: Mar 21 2015 20:27:49)
$ php -r "printx();"
$ tail -1 /tmp/php_errors.log
[23-Apr-2015 10:02:13 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function printx() in Command line code on line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`phpinfo()`でどの`php.ini`を見ているか確認してみるのかどうでしょう？
cliでの実行でしたら`php -i | grep ini`とかで出ると思います。

Comment: どのphp.iniを使ってるか調べることが出来るのですね。でも残念ながらdate.timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo'の入ったiniを見ているようです。